# lisp: required argument to defun not a symbol

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, clisp

When porting legacy code from clisp to sbcl, I encountered syntax which raised a problem illustrated by this code which runs without apparent error in clisp:

```
(defun foo ((alpha integer))
  (princ (type-of alpha))
  (princ " ")
  (prin1 alpha)
  (terpri))
(foo 3)
(foo 3.5)
(foo (list "beta" "gamma" "delta"))
;;; output follows ;;;
(INTEGER 0 281474976710655) 3
SINGLE-FLOAT 3.5
CONS ("beta" "gamma" "delta")
```

Apparently `integer` in the first line acts purely as commentative decoration.

sbcl, encountering the same definition of `#'foo`, complains:

```
Required argument is not a symbol: (ALPHA INTEGER)
```

What exactly is the purpose of `integer` here? Which of these two behaviors (if either) is standards compliant?

**EDIT:**

The legacy code in question is some (ancient) sort of `cl-lex`, but not [this one](https://github.com/djr7C4/cl-lex).

Comment: are you sure it was `defun` and not `defmethod`?

Comment: @rsm Yes, it was `defun`. You're seeing the code exactly as I ran it, and the output exactly as it outcame.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are relying on a CLISP extension [`CUSTOM:*DEFUN-ACCEPT-SPECIALIZED-LAMBDA-LIST*`](https://clisp.sourceforge.io/impnotes/evaluation.html#defun-accept-spelalist):

```
(defun foo ((alpha integer)) ; non-standard
  ...)
```

is equivalent to

```
(defun foo (alpha) ; ANSI CL conformant
  (declare (type integer alpha))
  ...)
```

when `custom:*defun-accept-specialized-lambda-list*` is `t`.

This extension makes [`defun`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defun.htm)
look a little bit like [`defmethod`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defmet.htm).
However, CLISP [ignores type declarations](https://clisp.sourceforge.io/impnotes/declarations.html), 
so the only effect this code decoration has is documentation of the programmer's intent.

SBCL does not support this extension, so you get the same error from it
that you would get from CLISP with
`custom:*defun-accept-specialized-lambda-list*` set to `nil`:

```
*** - FUNCTION: (ALPHA INTEGER) is not a symbol
```

PS. This feature was introduced in CLISP 13 years ago in the summer of 2004. I wonder which package uses it.

Comment: Mindblowing! Two questions, please: (1) Is CLISP's ignoring of type declarations considered a bug, or a feature? and (2) Do I owe you another zorkmid?

Comment: "A feature is a bug with tenure". In this case, it is an original design decision. Further, the CLISP behavior is fully standards compliant. If you want more details, ask a separate question. ;-)

Comment: CL is very confusing when it comes to the fact that all optimization hints can be ignored. Thus one cannot really rely on them.

Comment: Implementations are allowed to ignore type declarations, see [here in ANSI CL](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/sec_3-3-1.html). If you want type checks that persist across all implementations and all [safety](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/dec_optimize.html) settings, use the [check-type](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/mac_check-type.html) macro.

Comment: It took me this long to get it through my bird-brain that "I wonder which" was a question. The package is an ancient sort of cl-lex, but not the (probably much better) one at github, whose link I've edited into my original question. (Thanks for your patience in waiting for this answer.)